# React js chat when scrolling up load old messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, material-ui, chat

[image]

I am developing a `chat`, as can be seen from the image.

When the chat opens, the chat `scrolls down` to show the latest messages.

What I would like to do, that when user `scrolls up` and gets to the last message (i.e. the oldest one in the chat), the `oldMessage` function is called which makes an `http call` passing the `current page` to try to retrieve the `previous messages` to the last displayed at the top.

I don't know if I've made myself clear.

Can you give me a hand?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wind-peqfb?file=/src/components/App.js)

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  Card,
  Typography,
  Icon,
  useTheme,
  TextField,
  IconButton,
  Avatar,
  Paper
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import clsx from "clsx";
import moment from "moment/moment";

const message = [
  {
    id: 1,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "Hi, James!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "Hi, Vesper!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "Quickly come to the meeting room 1B, we have a big server issue",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "I’m having breakfast right now, can’t you wait for 10 minutes?",
    senderId: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "I’m having breakfast right now, can’t you wait for 10 minutes?",
    senderId: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "We are losing money! Quick!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    createdAt: "",
    message:
      "It’s not my money, you know. I will eat my breakfast and then I will come to the meeting room.",
    senderId: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "You are the worst!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "We are losing money! Quick!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "You are the worst!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    createdAt: "",
    message: "We are losing money! Quick!",
    senderId: {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Vesper",
      surname: "Lynd"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    createdAt: "",
    message:
      "It’s not my money, you know. I will eat my breakfast and then I will come to the meeting room.",
    senderId: {
      _id: 1,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond"
    }
  }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  messageRow: {
    position: "relative",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 16px 4px 16px",
    flex: "0 0 auto",
    "&.contact": {
      "& $bubble": {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        color: theme.palette.getContrastText(theme.palette.background.paper),
        borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
        borderTopRightRadius: 20,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
        marginLeft: 28,
        "& $time": {
          marginLeft: 12
        }
      },
      "&.first-of-group": {
        "& $bubble": {
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20
        }
      },
      "&.last-of-group": {
        "& $bubble": {
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 20
        }
      }
    },
    "&.me": {
      paddingLeft: 40,

      "& $avatar": {
        order: 2,
        margin: "0 0 0 16px"
      },

      "& $bubble": {
        marginLeft: "auto",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
        borderTopRightRadius: 5,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 5,
        "& $time": {
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          right: 0,
          marginRight: 12
        }
      },
      "&.first-of-group": {
        "& $bubble": {
          borderTopRightRadius: 20
        }
      },

      "&.last-of-group": {
        "& $bubble": {
          borderBottomRightRadius: 20
        }
      }
    },
    "&.contact + .me, &.me + .contact": {
      paddingTop: 20,
      marginTop: 20
    },
    "&.first-of-group": {
      "& $bubble": {
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        paddingTop: 13
      }
    },
    "&.last-of-group": {
      "& $bubble": {
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
        paddingBottom: 13,
        "& $time": {
          display: "flex"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  avatar: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    margin: 0
  },
  bubble: {
    position: "relative",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 12,
    maxWidth: "100%",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1]
  },
  message: {
    whiteSpace: "pre-wrap",
    lineHeight: 1.2
  },
  time: {
    position: "absolute",
    display: "none",
    width: "100%",
    fontSize: 11,
    marginTop: 8,
    top: "100%",
    left: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  },
  bottom: {
    // background: theme.palette.background.default,
    // borderTop: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13)'
  },
  inputWrapper: {
    borderRadius: 24
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    userMyInfo: {
      id: 1,
      name: "James",
      surname: "Bond"
    },
    chat: message,
    msgState: "",
    pag: 0
  });

  const { userMyInfo, chat, msgState } = state;

  const sendMessage = () => {};

  const oldMessage = () => {
    //http request
    fetch("")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((message) => {
        setState(...(prev) => ({ ...prev, chat: [...message, ...prev.chat] }));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  useEffect(scrollToBottom, []);

  const shouldShowContactAvatar = (item, i) => {
    return (
      (chat[i + 1] && chat[i].senderId._id !== chat[i + 1].senderId._id) ||
      !chat[i + 1]
    );
  };

  const isFirstMessageOfGroup = (item, i) => {
    return (
      i === 0 || (chat[i - 1] && chat[i - 1].senderId._id !== item.senderId._id)
    );
  };

  const isLastMessageOfGroup = (item, i) => {
    return (
      i === chat.length - 1 ||
      (chat[i + 1] && chat[i + 1].senderId._id !== item.senderId._id)
    );
  };

  return (
    <Paper
      elevation={3}
      className={clsx(classes.root, "flex flex-col relative pb-64")}
    >
      <Card elevation={1} className="flex flex-col h-512 rounded-8">
        <div
          className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-between px-24 h-64"
          style={{
            background: "#607d8b"
            //color: theme.palette.getContrastText('#607d8b')
          }}
        >
          <Typography className="text-center text-16 font-400">Chat</Typography>
        </div>
        <div style={{ flex: 1, overflowY: "auto" }}>
          {state.chat.length === 0 ? (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              Al momento non ci sono messaggi
            </div>
          ) : (
            state.chat.map((item, key) => (
              <div
                key={key}
                className={clsx(
                  classes.messageRow,
                  { me: item.senderId._id === userMyInfo.id },
                  { contact: item.senderId._id !== userMyInfo.id },
                  { "first-of-group": isFirstMessageOfGroup(item, key) },
                  { "last-of-group": isLastMessageOfGroup(item, key) }
                )}
              >
                {item.senderId._id !== userMyInfo.id &&
                  shouldShowContactAvatar(item, key) && (
                    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                      {item.senderId.name[0]} {item.senderId.surname[0]}
                    </Avatar>
                  )}
                <div className={classes.bubble}>
                  <div className={classes.message}>{item.message}</div>
                  <Typography className={classes.time} color="textSecondary">
                    {moment(item.time).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")}
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          )}
          <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
        </div>
        <div style={{ padding: 5, display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <TextField
            required
            id="outlined-required"
            label="Message"
            //inputRef={textInput}
            placeholder="Message"
            //onChange={handleChange}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
          <IconButton onClick={() => sendMessage()} disabled={msgState === ""}>
            <Icon>send</Icon>
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: So, you want to call a method when your container is scrolled to top?

Comment: @nadia: Yes, just like you do in chats, when you go up to the last message the oldest received should take the messages that proceeded calling a function.
Except it's not the whole page I'm interested in, but one div in particular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for scrolling and check you are at the top of the container

```
const  handleScroll = e => {
   let element = e.target;
   if (element.scrollTop===0) {
     //fetch messages
   }
}

 <div style={{ flex: 1, overflowY: "auto"}} onScroll={ handleScroll}>
```

Comment: Thx, it works, in the end I changed the works like this: `const handleScroll = ({target: {scrollTop}}) => {}`.

The problem was having to try to keep the current position (top) when the old messages arrived, I think I more or less succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can do is

1. Monitor for scroll event on an element using onScroll from react

   `<ScrollableComponent  onScroll={this.handleScroll}   />`
2. use the windows scroll event handler and detect when user is at top of page

   `useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
   return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
   }`

   const handleScroll = (event) => {
   // code here
   }